# Return value executing a method?

Tags: java, return

```js
import java.util.*;

public class Guess {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
      Random r = new Random();
      intro();
      int numGames = 0;
      int numGuesses = game(console, r);
      int max = max(numGuesses);
      String again = "y";
      do {
         game(console, r);
         System.out.println("Do you want to play again?");
         again = console.next();
         System.out.println();
         numGames++;
      } while (again.startsWith("y") || again.startsWith("Y"));
      stats(numGames, numGuesses, max);
   }

   public static void intro() {...}
   
   public static int game(Scanner console, Random r) {
      System.out.println("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100...");
      int answer = r.nextInt(100) + 1;
      System.out.println("answer = " + answer);
      int guess = -1;
      int numGuesses = 0;
      while (answer != guess) {
         System.out.print("Your guess? ");
         guess = console.nextInt();
         numGuesses++;   
         if (guess > answer) {
            System.out.println("It's lower.");
         } else if (guess < answer) {
            System.out.println("It's higher.");
         } else {
            System.out.println("You got it right in " + numGuesses + " guesses");
         }
         max(numGuesses);
      }
      return numGuesses;
   }
   
   public static int max(int numGuesses) {
      int max = numGuesses;
      if (max > numGuesses) {
         max = numGuesses;
      }
      return max;
   }
   
   public static void stats(int numGames, int numGuesses, int max) {
      System.out.println("Overall results:");
      System.out.println("    total games   = " + numGames);
      System.out.println("    total guesses = " + numGuesses);
      System.out.println("    guesses/game  = " + numGuesses / numGames / 1.0);
      System.out.println("    best game     = " + max);
   }
}
```

So this is a small part of my program and the problem I'm having is that my initial int for numGuesses (`int numGuesses = game(console, r);`) is executing the game method shown below. 
All I want from the game method is the return value of numGuesses so that I can forward the value into a different method called stats(numGames, numGuesses, max); . How do I make it so that the initial value isn't executing the method and only the do/while loop is? 
Is the way I produce a return statement wrong? Also, my return values aren't saving in my stats method so when I run it, I get the wrong answers.

Comment: Your method `max` is totally messed up... really.

Comment: I am not getting the line in your stats method
System.out.println("    guesses/game  = " + numGuesses / numGames / 1.0);

Answer (score 0):

Then you should put the code that's responsible of generating `numGuesses` in another method that you will use on both `main` and `game`, for example:

```
public static int game(Scanner console, Random r) {
    int numGuesses = getNumberOfGuesses(..);
    //continue implementation here
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numGuesses = getNumberOfGuesses(..);
    //use value 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get familiar with class variables. At the top of your class, you can declare a variable and also give it a value. That is what you should do with numGuesses if you want to access it from different methods in your class. Here is the Foobar example:

```
class Foo {

    private int bar = 0;

    private void foobar(int arg) {...}

}
```

You just need to watch out that you don't do `int numGuesses` somewehere in a method as that would create a second **local** variable. The class variable can be accessed via just the name.

---

Next, you want to keep track of the total games played and the total guesses. You can guess now (hahaha), that you need to use class variables as well. If you need to keep track of the total guesses even when the program is restarted you will need to store these values in a file, but that will be for another time.

---

Finally, two more little things.

1.) The method `max`. I do not know what max should do, but at the moment it is just returning the value passed to it. Also the if statement will **never** execute (x can't be higher than x).

2.) You should maybe consider not making everything static. It obviously works that way, but that is not, what is called **object-oriented programming**.